# dev server global cache (Python)

Tags: google-app-engine

I hope someone can clarify this for me:

Does the GAE dev server also cache the Python global scope like the production server does?
I'm under the impression that it does not.
I can't find anything about this in the docs.

Thanks

Quint

Comment: What do you mean by "caching the global scope", and where did you get the idea that the production environment does it?

Comment: Well, in the production environment you can define a global variable in a module and GAE caches this in the memory of the current instance. So it is saved between requests. You can use this for instance to create a "real" memory cache that is local for the current instance. But in the dev server i noticed that it's not saved between requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does. But when you change code, the development server restarting and you have brand new namespace for your modules.

Python doesn't have "global scope" (like e.g. PHP has) between modules. It has namespaces. They are mostly modules namespaces (created when you do imports) and, as you know, [GAE caching imports](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/#Python_App_caching). This cache is alive while the instance is running. Instance in general is a python's process and python keep variables values in memory until there is at least one reference to them.

Since the development server simulates the production service, it works in the same way, but the difference is that devserver watches for changes you make to your files (and I notice not only files) and reloads them if needed. To guaranteed reset module import caching you also need to restart server like in production.

Comment: In addition there is a command line option to disable auto restarts  --automatic_restart [AUTOMATIC_RESTART]
                        restart instances automatically when files relevant to
                        their module are changed (default: True)

Comment: So if i don't change my code in between requests, my global variable in my module should persist? This is not what i'm seeing. It's being re-initialized every request even without code changes. Does it matter if i'm running in debugger or not?

Comment: And where is this --automatic_restart  parameter documented? I can't find it.

Comment: I did some testing but it's very unpredictable. I am not making any code changes and with this --automatic_restart=False parameter used, sometimes it caches the module for a few requests and then out of the blue it decides to import it again for the next x times. I'm assuming this is a dev server quirk.